# increasing the height of imageView in gridView android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am using GridView first time. Everything is fine but the image height is less. I searched a lot but couldn't get the method of increasing the height of image through XML. Here is my code :

**activity_select_images.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
android:fillViewport="false">

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SelectImagesActivity">

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Please Select the pictures you like"
    android:id="@+id/selectTextview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectTextview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

  </FrameLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

**gridview_layout.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <ImageView android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbImage"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thumbImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="61dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**SelectImagesActivity.java**

```
package com.houssup.userapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelectImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int count = 0;
    Button btn;
    private Drawable marker, marker1;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_images);
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic_five);
        marker1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic_two);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, marker, marker1));


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (count < 5)
                    Toast.makeText(SelectImagesActivity.this, "Please " +
                            "select total 5 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private Drawable drawable1, drawable2;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        int positionID[];

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, Drawable drawable1,
                            Drawable drawable2) {
            this.context = context;
            this.drawable1 = drawable1;
            this.drawable2 = drawable2;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View gridView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from grid_item.xml ( Defined Below )

                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, null);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) gridView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                if (position < 5) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(marker);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(marker1);
                }
                // set image based on selected text


            } else {

                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by less? You have definded the `height` of the `GridView` as `500dp` but your `ImageView` the size is only set to `160dp`... You could increase the `height` there... but i don't know if this is what you want...

Comment: @user0815 Increasing the height in the ImageView just increases the space between the 2 rows of the GridView

Comment: Then the problem could be the ratio of the image (e.g 16:9 in a 4:3 `ImageView`)... Then you would need to set the `ImageView.ScaleType` to something like `CenterCrop` or something similar...

Comment: @user0815 no that's not the problem !!

Comment: Can you provide some link with an image showing your problem?

Comment: Try to set the `height` and `width` of the `RelativeLayout` in `gridview_layout.xml` to `wrap_content`...